# Prevent list from wrapping under inline block?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to center this list, but when I add inline-block, it wraps. So how can I make this list not wrap and display vertically in a single line? White-space: nowrap doesn't seem to work, and I am all out of other ideas to try to fix it.

```css
.mobile-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:  0;
    width: 4rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgba(243, 244, 246, 1.0);
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.nav {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    transform: scale(-1);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    background-color: coral;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- left side container -->
<div class="fixed top-0 bottom-0 left-0 w-16 border-r border-gray-100 z-10 mobile-nav">
<!-- left side container content -->
<div class="fixed bottom-16 left-0 w-16 select-none">
    <!-- navigation -->
    <nav class="nav block w-full text-center">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- end navigation -->
</div>
</div> <!-- end left side container -->
```

Comment: why use `inline-block` in the first place and not `flexbox`?

Comment: Want it centered.

Comment: and? flexbox can be used to center elements vertically and horizontally. So again, why `inline-block` instead of `flexbox`?

Comment: Can you give me an example? It doesn't center when I use flexbox.

Comment: remove: `.nav li { display: inline-block; };` add: `.nav ul { display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; align-items: center; }`

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written in the comment, I would actually solve this with `flexbox` instead. for that you should first remove: `nav li { display: inline-block; }`
This line will be superfluous and might cause issues with a flexbox solution.

To use flexbox we first need to enable it by adding: `nav ul { display: flex; }`

To have the the list-items below each other instead of next to each other, we need to add: `nav ul { flex-direction: column-reverse; }`. `flex-direction` determines in which direction the items will be aligned to each other. as we want them to be below each other we use `column`.

last but not least we need to add: `nav ul { justify-content: center; }`. This line will center the element at the vertical center. Which is the actual thing you aimed for.

```css
.mobile-nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 4rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgba(243, 244, 246, 1.0);
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  transform: scale(-1);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  background-color: coral;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- left side container -->
<div class="fixed top-0 bottom-0 left-0 w-16 border-r border-gray-100 z-10 mobile-nav">
  <!-- left side container content -->
  <div class="fixed bottom-16 left-0 w-16 select-none">
    <!-- navigation -->
    <nav class="nav block w-full text-center">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Test 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Test 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Test 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Test 4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Test 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation -->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end left side container -->
```

Answer (score -1):

now it s all vertical

```css
.mobile-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:  0;
    width: 4rem;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgba(243, 244, 246, 1.0);
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.nav {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    transform: scale(-1);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    background-color: coral;
    white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- left side container -->
<div class="fixed top-0 bottom-0 left-0 w-16 border-r border-gray-100 z-10 mobile-nav">
<!-- left side container content -->
<div class="fixed bottom-16 left-0 w-16 select-none">
    <!-- navigation -->
    <nav class="nav block w-full h-full text-center flex flex-col justify-center">
        <ul class="flex no-wrap flex-col justify-center h-full align-items-center>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Test 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- end navigation -->
</div>
</div> <!-- end left side container -->
```

Comment: Yes, but now it's not centered.

Comment: When one is still getting used to the details of the box model in HTML and CSS, using flex box can make it difficult to understand how to achieve what is needed. Add [this](https://caniuse.com/?search=flexbox) to the equation, and you've got yourself a perfect formula for trouble. Flex box is somewhat complicated to understand when learning CSS layouts. This is why I recommended display: inline-block yesterday. Still would like to understand exactly what your needs are. Good luck anyway! Maybe a little diagram with any little piece of software would shine a light on it, and we all learn!

Comment: @lanpierre I believe you commented the wrong post. Your link about flexbox support is way outdated. It must be from 2012. Since 2013 you support for Opera and the last bugs with Opera where fixed in 2015. IE fully supports flexbox aswell.

Comment: Is this reference incorrect: https://caniuse.com/?search=Flexbox. Also, as mentioned in my comment: the amount of parameters and the logic itself is not intuitive and understanding the foundation of the box model before is fundamental. Is this not correct?

Comment: Another mention on issues one can run into with flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox

Comment: A whole github site dedicated to Flexbugs: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs is also available. Never easy to use when you don’t understand the properties of the box model altogether.

Comment: [And the question posed by Tony the day before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67767669/how-to-center-text-that-is-writing-modes-vertically-written/67767975#67767975)